# Django FileNotFoundError at /admin

Tags: python, django

I have model registered on admin page:

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    cat = models.IntegerField()
    quest = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    path = models.FilePathField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cat} - {self.quest}'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

and I can see a database through admin page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuCcX.png

but I can't click on any record of the table and modify it due to an error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6W5a.png

I did it many times since now, and I have never encountered such an error.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you register the app in the settings.py?

Comment: Yes, I registered it.

Comment: Try `from .models import *`, make sure no migration left and no spelling error, then restart django and clear cache in browser

Comment: I checked it many times before posting it here.

Comment: can you add the `models.py` please

Comment: There is my **models.py**:  `from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):

    cat = models.IntegerField()
    quest = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    path = models.FilePathField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cat} - {self.quest}'
`

Answer (score 2):

Acorrding to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/) `FilePathField()` has one required argument `path`, which is:

"The absolute filesystem path to a directory from which this FilePathField should get its choices."

So you need modify your **models.py**:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    path = models.FilePathField(path='/home/images')
    ...
```